# Find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = e^{-2x}$, and find the interval of convergence for the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = e^{-2x}$, and find the interval of convergence for the series.

I got the maclaurin series to be this

$e^x = 1 - 2\frac{x}{1!} + 2^2\frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2)^n x^n}{n!}$$

Using the ratio test to find the interval of convergence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \frac{n!}{(-1)^n 2^n x^n} \right| = 2|x| \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} = 2|x|(0) < 1$$

Therefore for any value of x is in the interval of convergence. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Do I need to check the endpoints at x = 0, or no? Im a bit confused when the ratio test gives $\infty$ or zero. If its $\infty$ instead of 0, so like $2|x|\infty > 1$ Can I say there is no point in the interval that is convergence?

Comment: The limit is 0 regardless of the value of $x$, so no need to check anything else

Comment: There are no endpoints to check. The interval of convergence is $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: What happens if its $2|x|\infty > 1$ ?. As in instead of 0 i put infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The series representation for the exponential function converges everywhere (uniformly as well), as so any related sum will also converge everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This Maclaurin series is valid for $|x|<\infty$.

You know this because the series is valid over that domain. There are no points where the function "blows up".

By convention, the Maclauren series in centered about $x=0$. A power series allows three possibilities:

1. Series converges *only* at $x=0$.
2. Series converges on an interval centered at $x=0$.
3. Series converges for all values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$.